# Is there a signal standard for wireless mice?

Tags: mouse, wireless-mouse

I have a wireless mouse (OEM, no information whatsoever) for which I lost the dongle which connects to the PC.

I would like to replace it and I am wondering whether there is any standard for the signal of such low cost mice? (in that case, hopefully there could be a standard dongle).

I tried the one I have with my [Logitech K400 keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r?crid=26) but it did not work.

Just in case: the mouse

[image]

Comment: No; Its not standard.  While most wireless mice work the same, over 2.4ghz, the transmission is more often then not encrypted.  Unless its Bluetooth which is standardized accross the board.

Answer (score -1):

I've come across this so many times from clients and had no joy sadly.

In fact we had a keyboard and mouse set from Logitech once that the dongle was lost for. We knew the make and model so got a replacement dongle, this also did not work, so they sent another, again it failed. We then spoke to a senior engineer at Logitech who explained that they are sent out in batches of which the Dongles are configured/created for the batch, so we had to send the whole kit back to be 'paired' with a compatible dongle and sent back.

Sorry for the bad news but its highly unlikely you'll get that working.

Comment: how is it not useful your not gonna get it working... exactly what Ramhound advised above...?